# Typescript Error for align in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
<Grid item xs={12} align="center">
```

gives me

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: Element; item: true; xs: 12; align: string; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; item: true; xs: 12; align: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'align' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | GridSize>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.ts(2769)
OverridableComponent.d.ts(17, 7): 'component' is declared here.
(JSX attribute) xs?: boolean | GridSize | undefined
```

Note that im using tsx btw, no idea why this is throwing at me. I changed my file extension to jsx and everything works fine (also the Grid is from material ui)

also, the problem is occurring in the `align="center" part, if i remove that no errors will appear

I've also tried changing align to alignItems and alignContent, that solves the error; however it doesnt make the content align to the center

On a side note, not sure whether related or not: on the same file, I have a line:

```
<div style={{ align: "center" }}>
```

which also throws me an error of:

```
Type '{ align: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'align' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1760, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property like `align="center"` in Material UI. [Here](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) you can read that there is `justify="center"` and `alignItems="center"`. You can also see examples there so you can apply it to your project.

Additionally remember to use `<Grid container>` above `<Grid item>` to be able to manage it. Also `<Grid container>` can have item inside it like `<Grid container item>`. I had same problems before so I hope it will help you out.

Here you have a working solution - [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-85pz4)

Comment: Did that just now, the error stopped getting thrown at me, but the items aren't getting aligned to the center. I also changed the style for the div to `alignItems` just for good measures too.

Comment: Please share more code, I cannot help you out by just seeing one line with Grid. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-vvwoj here you have react+material playground, add this part of your code here and send a link, change App.jsx file only

Comment: Here's the link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-tdc5g?file=/app.jsx

Comment: so you want all elements to be in the center right?

Comment: Great thanks! I've found a workaround: by changing `xs={12}` to xs="auto" it centers the items for me for some reason too